# DropZone Plugin doesn't work when I call it with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dropzone.js

Plugin doesn't work when I call it with ajax.

Dropzone plugin: http://www.dropzonejs.com/

main.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/vendor/dropzone/dist/min/basic.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/vendor/dropzone/dist/min/dropzone.min.css">
</head>
<body>


  <div class="ajaxBlock">

  </div>

<script src="/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/vendor/dropzone/dist/min/dropzone.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $.post('/calling-page.html', function(result){
      $('.ajaxBlock').html(result);
    });
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

calling-page.html

```
<form action="/file-upload" class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone"></form>
```

Comment: put ur code on jsFiddle .. whats the error on console

Comment: @mKrl giving a `404` page not found with parameter being this number `_ 1505290759499` when I inspect the code.Gotten the solution??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to initialize it programmatically as follows:

As you are using `<form>` element; then no need of specifying `url:` option while initiating it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.post('/calling-page.html', function(result){
      $('.ajaxBlock').html(result);
      var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#my-awesome-dropzone");
    });
  });
```

OR

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $.post('/calling-page.html', function(result){
          $('.ajaxBlock').html(result);
          $("#my-awesome-dropzone").dropzone();
     });
});
```

Comment: Welcome @mKrgl... `:)`!